# Windows installer Error: "Object already exists"

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I'm using a Wix Installer to install a application on  Windows 7 Pro Machine. But Keep getting the error “Object already exists” during the installation.

The Installer works on other Machines.

This seems to happen with all installers, I tried installing Java, ITunes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer to this problem.

There was a Windows Security Update last month that was related to Windows Installer UAC and Granting Administrator Privileges to the User.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2918614

It’s been causing some problems with Installer.
http://ccmexec.com/2014/09/kb2918614-windows-installer-triggers-uac/

To remove this Update

1. Control Panel  Add Remove Programs  View Installed Updates
2. Find and Uninstall KB2918614 from the list of installed updates

Comment: Our QA department emailed me recently to let me know that as of the last set of windows updates, this issue no longer occurs.  Perhaps Microsoft released a fix.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way we can answer with the provided information. Please try to update your question with more information.

A good first step is to create a verbose log for the setup:

```
msiexec.exe /I "C:\Test.msi" /QN /L*V "C:\Temp\msilog.log"
```

Open the log in notepad and search for ["**value 3**"](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/8/2/the-first-thing-i-do-with-an-msi-log/) to find installation errors.

See **[msifaq.com](http://www.msifaq.com/)** for more details ([**logging faq entry**](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm)).